# Can a variable's setter call its getter

Tags: javascript

I am using ES5 getters and setters to get DB entries in a way that setting `<table>.<entry> = <value>` writes the value to a local cache, and the value is then synchronized with the DB later.

The getter's job is to get the entry from the cache if available, or to pull the result off the DB if not and return that. But it is also supposed to call the setter to cache the result for future queries.

The problem is, I don't know how to call the setter from inside the getter. I have tried `this.<entry> = <value>`, `<table>.<entry> = <value>` and `<entry> = <value>`, all of which result in an error about redeclaring a const (`<table>`).

So is there any way of doing this?

**EDIT:** Here's a minimal example to replicate the issue:

```
const table = {
    _entry: "Something",
    get entry(){ 
        /*Do Stuff*/ 
        this.entry = "Something else";  // Exception: SyntaxError: redeclaration of const table
        return this._entry;
    },
    set entry(value){
        /*Do Stuff*/
        this._entry = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. Where in an object getter/setter definitions would you use `const`? Assignment should just work.

Comment: @Bergi My code contains lots of unnecessary bits, but I've posted the important bits that cause the problem :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Add an `=` after `table`, evaluate `table.entry` - it gets `"Something else"` as expected. If you're getting a *SyntaxError: redeclaration of const table*, then that has to do with `const table` and nothing with the getters/setters in the object.

Comment: @Bergi the code in my question throws the very same error for me in Firefox (nightly) and Node.js

Comment: It only does if you are running some other code that already has declared `table` variable. The code from your question *alone* does not throw any errors.

Comment: @Bergi I tried running it alone in a scratchpad. Same error

Comment: Can you link that scratchpad, please?

Comment: @Bergi I meant the scratchpad that comes with Firefox Nightly. However, apparently that shares the `window` with the current tab, and that's why it was throwing an error. I presume the problem is somewhere else. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside the class(so to say) there is no need to go through getters to access class members. You can just use `this` as you suggested. If you are not allowed to do so it means your declaration is forbidding it. Evaluate changing the declaration if you have the need to change the inner state. It is difficult to say more with no code provided.

Comment: I know I can access the underlying variable, but I *want* to go through the setter to avoid duplicating code

Comment: @DividedByZero Ofc you can, just mention the setter function name when you need.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might be getting confused here. Are you saying I can use `this.<setter>` from inside the getter?

Comment: @DividedByZero yes. Or even just `<setter>`.

Comment: @DividedByZero With no real sample is difficult to give some more help.

Comment: I've added some code that illustrates the issue better to my question :)

Comment: You can't change because the object is `constant`, meaning that once the properties are intilized they can't be reassigned. Remove the `const` keyword.

Comment: I don't want to reassign the properties, I want to call the respective functions. In my example what I want to happen is that the getter uses the setter as it would be used from outside the object. So what should happen in my example is that `table._entry`'s value changes to "Something else", not `table.entry`'s

Comment: Apparently this was throwing an error because `table` already existed in the window. Your answer is right then. Thanks!

Comment: @DividedByZero Hard to think of that! :) Good luck!